# Curl to get logged in content failed

Tags: php, curl, cookies

My below code returned a blank screen, no error shown. I tested my script with other url, it work fine but not for this one, any idea?

```
$username = '123';
$pass = 'abc';

$login = array(
    'username' => $username,
    'password' => $pass,
    'login' => 'login'
);

$loginUrl = 'deleted';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($login));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

$content = curl_exec($ch);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://deleted/dashboard");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt');

$content2 = curl_exec($ch);

echo $content2;
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: *code returned a blank screen* check error.log file, check php ini settings, check if curl is enabled, use var_dump($content2); instead of echo $content2 ....

Comment: the curl is enabled, checked the log, nothing happen..

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I was tearing my hair out trying to figure out what was wrong, Worked fine on my machine but when testing on the server it just failed silently

I am assuming that you are running this on a server machine and said server machine has no Root CA Certificates installed. 
so it cannot verify the https server and fails silently (even though it works fine over http)

try

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

If this fails you could also try to add the equivilent of -v (verbose) to curl to get raw output. I could offer more help but its time for sleep now.